# How to interpret autoarima SARIMAX(1, 0, [1], 7)

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I've run this and was expecting to see something like: SARIMAX (#, #, #) x(#, #, #, #)

```
auto_arima(df['total'],seasonal=True,m=7).summary()
```

But I got this:

```
SARIMAX(1, 0, [1], 7)
```

How do I interpret this, so when I come to build my model I can use the correct parameters?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the values of P, D, Q are 1, 0, [1]. And the values of p,d,q are 0,0,0 if switch trace=True in the auto_arima() method.